# EF generating the wrong fk

Tags: c#, entity-framework, t-sql

I have two poco's

```
public class Person {
   [Key]
   public virtual int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual int? AtendeeId { get; set; }
   [ForeignKey("Id")]
   public virtual Atendee Atendeed { get; set; }
}

public class Atendee {
   [Key]
   public virtual int Id { get; set; }

   public virtual int PersonId { get; set; }
   public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

For some reason this creates a FK from atendee to person using the ID column of atendee instead of personId.  What would be the correct way of declaring this?

Here is the FK generated:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Atendees]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Atendees_dbo.People_Id] FOREIGN KEY([Id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[People] ([Id])
```

Comment: Are you trying for a one-to-one relationship, or something else? For general EF stuff, these tutorials helped me: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: It should be a zero to one realtionship, ie a person might have an atendee, but an atendee must have a person

Comment: Which EF version is this? EF6 only supports [Shared Primary Key Associations](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-3-shared-primary-key-associations).

Comment: I don't quite understand what that means, or how it affects my question. I'm using ef 6.1.3 for .net 4.5.2

Comment: What that means is exactly what you see: "using the ID column of atendee instead of personId". `personId` is a useless field in F6's 1:0..1 implementation.

Comment: How would you then move one atendee from one person to another? And would you make an answer, so I can mark it as anwswered.

Answer (score 3):

You only list the 'opposite' foreign key for a collection, ie for a 1-N relation.
You seem to have a 1-1 relation.

```
//[ForeignKey("Id")]
[ForeignKey("AtendeeId")]  // or just omit this
public virtual Atendee Atendeed { get; set; }
```

---

```
public class Person {
   [Key]
   public virtual int Id { get; set; }

   [ForeignKey("Atendeed")]  // refer to the property
   public virtual int? AtendeeId { get; set; }

   public virtual Atendee Atendeed { get; set; }
}
```

But you should consider using the fluent notation in override OnModelBuilding, that usually gives you more control.

Comment: I'm going for a zero to one realtionship

Comment: If I change to atendeeID i get the following error: The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'Atendeed' on type 'Norconsult.Models.Person' is not valid. The foreign key name 'AtendeeId' was not found on the dependent type 'Norconsult.Models.Atendee'. The Name value should be a comma separated list of foreign key property names.

Comment: If i omit the foreignkey, I get a blank migration, witch means the FK is still defined wrongly